# Getting array of date group by "some time interval" between a particular time span

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to **MySql** . I am trying to get some data from a web server of e-commerce website by placing a php file on it. I want to get only the **count** of all products sold or cancelled **everyday**. If no product is sold, It should return **0**. and I want to get details in particular **time span**, like every **week**, **month** or **year**. And I want to get the data in **array**. Like the sales in week is:

> 3,7,9,0,6,0,1

or with any separator. I have some part of working query but not all:

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM `ad_aff`
WHERE STATUS ='rejected'
AND datetime BETWEEN '2013-07-23' 
AND DATE_ADD('2013-07-23',INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
```

**PS:** I want to get **60** results from this query.. with **0's** on all places where no product is rejected

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY` to get the count for each date.

```
SELECT DATE(datetime) date_rejected, COUNT(*) ct
FROM ad_aff
WHERE STATUS = 'rejected'
AND datetime BETWEEN '2013-07-23' AND DATE_ADD('2013-07-23',INTERVAL 2 MONTH)
GROUP BY date_rejected
ORDER BY date_rejected
```

You can put them in an array in the PHP application that reads the results.

Comment: You need to left join this with a table containing all the dates. Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't have any built-in way to do this. Probably easier to fill in the gaps in the PHP code.

Comment: I don't know about left join. If you can provide some code or link?

Comment: Don't bother with the left join, since there's no table to join with. Just do it in the application.

Comment: I don't have a web site to recommend. But wherever you're learning MySQL from should explain it.